# Working with reportlab to create tables

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am trying to loop the user data in django to create a table with the help of reportlab. But I am running into an attributeError that 'tuple' object has no attribute 'username'.

```
def admin_tools_pdf(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;   filename="users.pdf" '  
buffer=BytesIO()
p=canvas.Canvas(buffer,pagesize=A4)
width, height = A4
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles["BodyText"]
styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT
styleBH = styles["Normal"]
styleBH.alignment = TA_CENTER
user_data=User.objects.all().values_list('username','email')
username=Paragraph("'<b>Username</b>'",styleBH)
email=Paragraph("'<b>Email Id</b>'",styleBH)
data=[[username,email]]
for i in user_data:
    username=str(i.username).encode('utf-8')
    email=str(i.email).encode('utf-8')
    user=Paragraph(username,styleN)
    mail=Paragraph(email,styleN)
    data+=[user,mail]
table=Table(data,colWidths=[4*cm,4*cm,4*cm,4*cm])
table.wrapOn(p, width, height)
table.wrapOn(p, width, height)
table.drawOn(p)
p.showpage()
p.save()
pdf=buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
response.write(pdf)
return response
```

The import files are:

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle,Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, cm 
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide your full log that error

Answer (score 1):

`values_list` returns a list of tuples, which do not support dot dereference. You want something like `username = i[0].encode('utf-8')`, or use `values` to get dicts instead and use `i['username'].encode('utf-8')`. Or use `User.objects.all().only('username', 'email')` - that will give you model instances with those fields loaded into memory and all other fields deferred, which would support dot reference.

I'd use `values()` for clarity - it's easier to tell what's going on than with `values_list`, while model instances are more heavyweight than you need and can hide the need to make extra queries or update your initial queryset if you do start needing further fields.

Comment: I fixed that but now I am getting a TypeError: iteration over non-sequence with respect to this line,     table=Table(data,colWidths=[4*cm,4*cm,4*cm,4*cm])